# How to Build waterless non composting toilets?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am a CEO of New Beginning Homes. I am looking into building a waterless non composting toilet. This toilet will be run using gears and a handle that turns the gears to push the waste through a decomposing process where the waste will then be able to be used again for agricultural purposes. I am already aware of incinerating toilets. Any ideas on what could be used to break down the waste and on what types of gears would be best for this type of thing?

Comment: There are companies already doing this.  For example, see Clivus New England in Lawrence Massachusetts.

Comment: I do not understand why my question was put on hold. How can I change it to fit the terms? And Olin Lathrop, thank you for the reply. I will look into that. Much appreciated.

Comment: The official reason your question was put on hold is because it was "opinion based".  The bigger issue is that you're basically asking for a design.  That's not how this site works.  For such broad questions, you really need to hire a engineer.  If you only want one temporarily, then consider hiring a consultant.  That can also get you access to expertise you need, but couldn't keep busy full time.

Comment: Oh, I see. Once again, thank you for taking the time to reply and explain to me. Have a good day.

Comment: A quick google search for 'macerator' showed many examples of dry mix and dry pumping systems that could be adapted for the system you suggest. Commercial dry toilets and waste composting systems are also commonly available.